# BeautifulSoup scraping returns {{}} that does not have data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a site that looks like below:

```
    <div class="address">
    <div class="hit-company"><a href="https://www.cools.biz/best/celebrities/amy-gold/">Amy  Gold</a></div>
    <div class="speciality hit-speciality">Audiology</div>
    <div class="address hit-address"><i><p translate="no">
    <span class="address-line1">38 Park Drive </span><br>
    <span class="locality">London</span>, <span class="administrative-area">VA</span> <span class="postal-code">22025</span><br>
    </p></i></div>
    <div class="phone hit-phone"><i><a href="tel:+1-xxx-659-xxx">(xxx) 659-xxx</a></i></div>
    <div class="description hit-listing_description hidden-xs"></div>
    <div class="hit-website"><a href="http://coll celebs.com" target="_blank">Visit Website</a></div>
    </div>
```

Used beautiful soups to scrape this:`

```
import os
from urllib.request import Request, urlretrieve, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = Request("https://www.urlxxxxxx.com", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}) 
page1 = urlopen(req)
phtml = BeautifulSoup(page1, 'html5lib') print(phtml)
divs = phtml.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"hit-company"})
print('aaaaa-----' + str(divs))`
```

Tried with html5lib, lxml, html.parser. lxml and html.parser do not even pick up the div class "hit-company" only html5lib does. even with html5lib, divs is coming out to be an empty.

When I examine the html output I notice

```
<div class="hit-company{{person}}</div>
<div class="speciality hit-speciality">{{specialty}}</div>
<span class="address-line1">{{address}}</span><br>
```

The actual data is being placed by {{paratemer x}}. Can you please help solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you share the link to the page you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Thanks, it was an internal page. But solved it. It is the same problems of scraping with dynamically generated JS - just use selenium and phantomJS

Answer (score 0):

**Based on the comment by [@crossal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8826008/crossal):**

The site being scraped (an internal page) had dynamically generated content, and the problem was solved by using [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) and [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).